# How to measure dice coefficient of two images

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, metrics, scikit-image

I have two identical RGB images and try to find the dice coefficient. I would expect the result to be 1.0, but instead it is 0.0039.

What do i do wrong??

```
from skimage.io import imread

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1
    y_true_f = y_true.flatten()
    y_pred_f = y_pred.flatten()
    intersection = (sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f))
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (sum(y_true_f) + sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

im=imread(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Examine_unet_CAMvid\imga.png')
print(dice_coef(im,im))
```

[image]

Comment: Or instead of `np.sum`, use `np.count_nonzero`.

Comment: Bilal the values are uint8 .Thank you for the advise anyway`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from keras import backend as K
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
  smooth=1
  intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
  union = K.sum(y_true, axis=[1,2,3]) + K.sum(y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
  return = K.mean((2. * intersection + smooth)/(union + smooth), axis=0)
```

Comment: ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 3 for input with 3 dimensions. for 'Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [320,320,3], [3] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 2 3>.

Comment: What are the shapes of y_true and y_pred ? and check this out https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3611